# How To Package Binary Projects Using Conan?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

### The Problem:

The package's consumer couldn't load the package's binary's shared libraries.

```
find_package(MyThirdParty REQUIRED) # MyThirdParty is installed using Conan
find_program(binary_paty MyThirdParty REQUIRED)
execute_process(COMMAND ${binary_path} COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL ANY)
```

The `execute_process` command will fail because the `MyThirdParty`'s shared libraries are missing.

How could I package the third-party binary projects?

### The Minimal Reproducible Example:

Third-party project:

```
file(WRITE Library.hh "void Func();")
file(WRITE Library.cc "void Func() {}")
add_library(Library SHARED Library.hh Library.cc)

file(WRITE Main.cc "#include \"Library.hh\"\nint main() { Func(); }")
add_executable(MyThirdParty Main.cc)
target_link_libraries(MyThirdParty PRIVATE Library)

install(TARGETS MyThirdParty Library EXPORT MyThirdPartyConfig)
install(EXPORT MyThirdPartyConfig
  NAMESPACE MyThirdParty::
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/MyThirdParty
)
```

My attempt for packaging the third-party with Conan:

```py
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools

class MyThirdPartyConan(ConanFile):
  name = "MyThirdParty"
  version = "1.0.0"
  settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"

  def source(self):
    tools.download(
      filename = "CMakeLists.txt",
      url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gccore/9007084e1b307592ae040ceb5745bf5f/raw/419a96712145e8d24d4c9982ab3b7fd31d44b9f0/CMakeLists.txt")

  def build(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    cmake.configure()
    cmake.build()

  def package(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    cmake.install()
```

The consumer:

```
find_package(MyThirdParty REQUIRED)
find_program(binary_paty MyThirdParty REQUIRED)
execute_process(COMMAND ${binary_path} COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL ANY)
```

And finally the `conanfile.txt`:

```
[requires]
MyThirdParty/1.0.0@Ghasem/Test

[generators]
cmake_find_package
```

But the consumer's CMake with the Conan package fails because of the third-party's shared library. When the consumer's CMake tries to execute the `MyThirdParty` binary it will fail because it couldn't find the `libLibrary.so` file.

---

**My Environment:**

- **OS:** `Fedora 35`
- **Kernel:** `Linux 5.18.9-100.fc35.x86_64`
- **Compiler:** `GCC 11.3.1 20220421`
- **CMake:** `3.22.2`
- **Conan:** `1.47.0`

Comment: ``cmake_find_package`` generator is legacy, I'd recommend trying to move to CMakeDeps. Then the issue seems related to the lack of LD_LIBRARY_PATH definition, which can be solved using the ``ConanBuildEnv`` generator. It would be important to clarify, if the consumer is going to use it as a "tool", then it might be better used as a ``tool_require``, because it will fit the model better, and work for cross-build scenarios too. I'd recommend submitting this as an issue to https://github.com/conan-io/conan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux we could use `patchelf` and change the binary RPATH during the packaging state:

```py
def package(self):
  cmake = CMake(self);
  cmake.install();
  self.run("patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN/../lib' " +
    self.package_folder + "/bin/MyThirdParty");
```

And for Windows just put the shared libraries files besides the binary, the Windows Linker/Loader doesn't try hard to be smart(like Linux's Linker/Loader does).